# asp.net vs asp.net mvc or wpf broswer based application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, wpf

I need to make an application that will be used over the internet.

**Detail:** My application would be a some kind of word processor like ms-office (i know i can't make ms-office but can add some functionalities) in which any body can come and write documents for eg. (Applications,essay,books ,etc...) in our national language.

I have considered three options ASP.NET MVC and WPF (web) and ASP.NET(Web Forms).
WPF Web Browser applications can be accessed on IE and Firefox.

What are the pros and cons of using ASP.NET MVC and WPF (web) and ASP.NET(Web Forms) over the Internet ?ms-office is a desktop application can i acheive maximum functionalities by using web ?
Any suggestion would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You probably want ASP.NET MVC.

### Windows Presentation Form (WPF)

WPF is used more for desktop Applications rather than web applications. It probably isn't viable for this situation.

### ASP.NET MVC

ASP.NET MVC is Microsoft's current method of developing Web Applications. From personal experience, it's a great system. It does have a bit of a learning curve but it shouldn't be too tough to pick up. There's a lot of good resources out there to learn it. I would recommend this for building a web application.

### ASP.NET Web Forms

Web Forms is Microsoft's older way to develop web applcations. ASP.NET MVC is build off of this platform, but development doesn't resemble it in any way. It's a lot less robust system than MVC and doesn't have a very active community for help.

---

If you're looking for a good in browser text editor with options similar to Microsoft Word, I'd look at [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/). I've used it and it's pretty easy to work with.

Comment: No problem. Hope I was able to help.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider **ASP.NET Web Forms** or **ASP.NET MVC 3+**.

As [Thomasov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5450333/thomasov) mentioned, **WPF is intended to make Desktop Applications**. It may be possible to make a [WPF Web Site](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480223.aspx), but don't. ASP.NET Web Forms and ASP.NET MVC are much better solutions for internet applications.

ASP.NET Web Forms is the older version of ASP.NET MVC. Web Forms and MVC have syntactic differences, feature differences, as well as performance differences. MVC will definitely perform better for a larger application and give you more flexibility than the older counterpart.

It is possible to get all the functionality from Microsoft Word into a web site, but this will entail a lot of time and effort. Everything is possible in the world of programming! ;)

[Google Docs](https://docs.google.com/document/u/0/) is a good example of a Web version to Microsoft Word, though not completely covering all of the functionality Microsoft Word has. I'm sure there are other examples as well.